# How to get data from db using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to get bio from db using those:

```
<body>
 <div id="t1" class ="aDiv">
  <h2 id="tlh">Lois</h2>
   <div id="tabs1">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#ltab1" onClick="whonext()">Lois</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ltab2" onClick="getBio('Lois','ltab2')">Bio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ltab3" onClick="getFans()">Fans</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ltab4" onClick="">Fan of</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And PHP:

```
<?php
 include("dbconnect.php");
 $username=$_GET['username'];
 $query = "select bio from cast where username = '$username'";
 $link = mysql_query($query);
 if (!$link) {
   die($query);
 }
 $rows = array();
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($link)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
 }
 $json=json_encode($rows);  
 echo $json;
 ?>
```

The AJAX request initiated by Tab 2 is processed at the server by a script called getbio.php.

I am totally new to webdesign and frankly I still don't quite understand functions.... it has been only 1,5 month since i started to learn. Could anyone help me?
Thank you,
Aga

Answer (score 0):

The following should work as long as you have jQuery imported. I wasn't sure what your second parameter was supposed to achieve, so just called it 'el'.

```
function getBio(name, el) {
    $.get('/getbio.php?username=' + name, function(data) {
        // use data to update whatever you need
    });
}
```

The first parameter in the `jQuery.get()` function is the Url to send the request to, and the second is the success function. To add a fail function, you could add a `.fail()` handler to the end of the `get` function.

Comment: Ok but where is AJAX in it? The sample functions from my course where looking like below:function getBroons() {  // the page load function
  var myurl="scripts/getbroons.php";
   $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: myurl, dataType:'json', // a JSON object will be returned from the server.
    success: function(thebroons){ // it works!

Comment: The `$.get` function is shorthand for the `$.ajax({type="GET"...` function so it is essentially the same

Comment: Thank you.It will sound silly but what you mean by second parameter then? I'm really sorry but we have never been told at school...

Comment: Which, for `getBio()` or the `$.get` function?

Comment: So, in your HTML/Javascript, you have an `onClick` defined for `getBio` taking two 'parameters' (Lois and ltab2). I assumed the first was the name of the person, but I wasn't sure why ltab2 was necessary.

Comment: Maybe it is not necessary. The thing is that the same function has to be used few times. I will have it in later html for 4 more people, all in different places, so i figured i need a second one, however i may be wrong.

Comment: You could pass in the element itself using `this` instead of `'ltab2'`. That would make it easier to update that element directly instead of searching for it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this is by using Node.js, however it seems that with an AJAX call:

```
function getBio(name, tab) {
  var xhttp; 
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("tlh").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("tlh").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getbio.asp?q="+name, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```